# Google Home Assistant : Connect Smart Home with Voice?

Tags: google-home, google-smart-home

I am developing smart device that helps visually impaired people identify objects. It currently links up with a mobile app with a voice over of object description (previously saved by a co-user). I wanted to use Google Home or Amazon Alexa for this purpose, the user scans the object and the smart speaker makes a voice output with the object description.

I understand that Amazon Alexa only has fixed schemas for their proactive events API so it may not be the best choice. I have limited experience with Google HA and was wondering if anybody who has experience with Google HA could help me out - specifically whether Google HA can work for this requirement or not?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Google Home doesn't currently support custom proactive events like the one you described. You might need to explore other options or platforms that allow more flexibility in implementing your specific requirements.

Consider exploring Google Home's [broadcast messages feature](https://support.google.com/googlenest/answer/7531913?sjid=8801693191211515521-NC), which allows sending voice messages to all Google Nest or Home devices. Additionally, you might find the [Assistant SDK helpful](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/), as it provides a way to integrate Google Assistant into your device, offering more customization options for your project.